# Hide modal when login form is succesfull

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, hide, mdbootstrap

Im just trying to close the modal if my login is succesfull.

When I add the basicModal.hide() method anywhere in my code the Login button disappears.

HTML:

```
<!-- loginModal -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="loginModalCenter" #loginModalCenter tabindex="-1" role="form" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle"
    aria-hidden="true">

....

          <!-- Sign in button -->
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block my-4" type="submit">Login</button>

        <!-- form login -->
```

TS:
.....

```
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService
      .login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value, result => {
        if (result) {
          console.log('Logged in ' + result);
          this.loginModalCenter.hide();
        } else {
          console.log('not a valid user');
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue. Elaborate your question further.

Comment: is the login button inside the modal ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean to do so.
Set a bool loggedIn = true on your class, then set a *ngIf="!loggedIn" on your loginModalCenter.

Finally simply set loggedIn to true on login function result.

So TS:

```
//before constructor()
loggedIn: boolean = false;


//On login
this.authenticationService
  .login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value, result => {
    if (result) {
      console.log('Logged in ' + result);
      this.loginModalCenter.hide();
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }
```

And on template:

```
<div class="modal fade" *ngIf="!loggedIn" id="loginModalCenter" #loginModalCenter tabindex="-1" role="form" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle"
aria-hidden="true">
```

Hope that helps !